# Can I execute command logic from different class in xaml

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, command

I have a common class DataGridRowCopyAction.

```cs
public class DataGridRowCopyAction
{
    public ICommand RowCopyCommand = new DelegateCommand(RowCopyAction)

    Private void RowCopyAction
    {
        // do something 
    }
}
```

Can I use RowCopyCommand as a common command inside multiple xamls
I tried below method .But it is not working

```xml
xmlns:b="clr-namespace:x.y"
Command={Binging path=b:RowCopyCommand}
```

Command

Comment: Of course you can do this.
But the implementation details depend on the specific conditions of the task.
The first thing that matters is whether the RowCopyAction method needs other members of the DataGridRowCopyAction instance?
If not, then you can make him and the team static members. If so, then we need an understanding of where and how you instantiate the DataGridRowCopyAction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have  any non-View model class where you for example defined you Command like this:

```
 namespace YourNameSpace
 {
    public class YourCommand : ICommand
    {
        public bool CanExecute(object par)
        {
            // Define your logic
            return true;
        }
    
        public void Execute(object par)
        {
            // Define the action you want             
        }
    
        public event EventHandler 

CanExecuteChanged;
        }    
      

}
```

You need to create an instance of the command logic class in your XAML or code-behind. For example, in your XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="YourApp.MainWindow"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:YourCommand x:Key="YourCommand" />
    </Window.Resources>
```

Finally, bindining and in your XAML controls, you can bind the Command property to the instance of your command logic class:

```
<Button Content="Execute Command" Command="{StaticResource YourCommand}" />
```

Comment: Thanks @Ferid. Well explained.It solved my problem.

Comment: All the best and no problem. I am glad to hear that. @AnuHardin